# How to instantiate a Platform (@ionic/angular) object

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a `Platform` (@ionic/angular) object but instead of doing it with the normal method (Dependency Injection):

```js
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I was trying to do it in a separate script, not in a page:

```js
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

class Test {
  constructor(){
    const plat = new Platform();
  }
}
```

I've managed to do this with a different plugin, `BluetoothLE`, but with `Platform` there are two parameters required: `doc: any, zone: NgZone`, which I don't know how to pass them. Is it possible to instantiate this object like this or should I just pass it as an argument of the class Test?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the question is WHY? what exactly is your us case for this?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I'm working with BluetoothLE and there is a specific method that needs to run only on android. As I'm creating a class outside the page component (where the dependency injection is made) I was trying to instantiate the Platform object there. Another way around this is to pass the platform in that class constructor, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you need to do that, when angular injection should make the same effect, but you can create an instance of Platform like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  plat: any;
  
  constructor() {
    this.plat = new Platform(null ,new NgZone({}))
  }
}
```

I think this is what you were looking for.

**EDIT**

If you are looking for a certain code to be executed only on Android you shouldn't initiate a new platform like you are trying to do, just to the function if the platform is Android:

```
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
   if(this.platform.is('android')){
      this.myfunctionForAndroidOnly();
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this too but it didn't work

Comment: I've edited my answer after seeing your comment on your original question